# rails cache on static page except language

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching

I've developed a ruby on rails app. Most of its content is static (does not deppend on database). It only changes deppending on the language.

I've defined the language as a part of the url. Ex: "mydomain/en/page" will be the english version.
I've defined a filter that, in case no language is specified in the url, it redirects him to its default:

```
def set_locale
        I18n.locale = params[:locale] || extract_browser_prefered_language || I18n.default_locale
        if params[:locale] == nil
            redirect_to url_for( :locale => I18n.locale )
        end
    end
```

Therefore when the user enters to "mydomain" he is redirected to "mydomain/en".

Now I want to add cache.
As I said before all the contents are static, I'll use "caches_page" for all the pages. This works when the user enters to a "mydomain/en", but not to "mydomain", because of the redirect filter.

Can I add a page cache only to the mydomain/en requests?
Any other idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it overwriding the cache_page function in the ApplicationController

```
class << self
    def cache_page content, path, p3, p4
        available = %w{ca es en}

        if available.include?(path.split("/")[1])
            super content, path, p3, p4
        end
    end
end
```